# How do I force the application to execute 3 observable sequently in angular using RxJS 6.4.0?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I saw several questions like this but there wasn't true solution for my problem.

I have two httpClient request one for edit and the other for select. I wish edit opration execute first and then select operation.

I find out there is an RxJS operator named as concat can do it.

I tried to implement it and my code is like this now:
(I know probably it isn't true code but this is what I understand)

submit method :

```
public subMit() {
  const streamOne = of(this.edit());
  const streamTwo = of(this.clear());
  const streamThree = of(this.fetch());
  const sourcefour = streamOne.pipe(delay(5000));
  const result = sourcefour.pipe(concat(streamTwo.pipe(concat(streamThree))));
  result.subscribe();
}
```

Edit, clear and fetch method :

```
public edit() {
  this.measServ.editbyid(this.meas._id, this.meas).subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('edited')
  );
}


public fetch() {
  this.measServ.getonebyid(this.myControl.value).subscribe(
    x => {
      this.meas._id = x._id;
      this.meas.measureTitle = x.measureTitle;
      this.meas.measureDescription = x.measureDescription;
      this.meas.measureSymbol = x.measureSymbol;
    }
  );
  console.log('fetch');
}


public clear() {
  this.meas._id = '';
  this.meas.measureTitle = '';
  this.meas.measureDescription = '';
  this.meas.measureSymbol = '';
  console.log('clear');
}
```

It is a practical project, my main goal is to see concat performance. So I want to set 5 seconds delay after edit operation responsed and then select data. but above code didn't work properly. just executed without delay. 
May be I didn't use true syntax or using depreciated elements.

Your true answer makes me happy.

Comment: *none* of your functions return an observable. There is *nothing* too concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import concat

```
import { of, concat } from 'rxjs';
```

concat require an observable so I have edit all method to return an observable

```
public subMit() {
  const streamOne = this.edit();
  const streamTwo = this.clear();
  const streamThree = this.fetch();
  const sourcefour = streamOne.pipe(delay(1500));
  const result = sourcefour.pipe(concat(streamTwo.pipe(concat(streamThree))));
  result.subscribe();
}
```

> the order of how you have pass the observable parameter to concat is
>   the order of execution sourcefour will reun first when it complate streamTwo will after that streamThree

```
public edit() {
  return this.measServ.editbyid(this.meas._id, this.meas)
    .pipe( finalize(() => console.log('1-edited')));
}

public fetch() {
  return this.measServ.getonebyid(this.myControl.value)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => console.log('3-fetched')),
      tap(
        x => {
          this.meas._id = x._id;
          this.meas.measureTitle = x.measureTitle;
          this.meas.measureDescription = x.measureDescription;
          this.meas.measureSymbol = x.measureSymbol;
          console.log('3-data moved to variable');
        }
      )
    );
}

public clear() {
  return of(1).pipe(
    tap(() => {
      this.meas._id = '';
      this.meas.measureTitle = '';
      this.meas.measureDescription = '';
      this.meas.measureSymbol = '';
      console.log('2-cleared');
    })
  );
}
```

read more about [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html)

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I applied your solution with some modifications and it worked properly. If you agree, I intend to make some modification in your answer. If so please inform me here. Then I'll check this answer as true solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using chained `mergeMap`

`mergeMap` accepts a function which returns an observable to which we can either subscribe or chain more `mergeMap`s within rxjs `pipe` function

Working example at

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-mergemap